# Adding more questions in your post after receiving an answer

Tags: discussion

I have recently answered this [question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962365/finding-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-in-several-variables) However, after my answer the OP made an edit which includes more questions. It says:

> EDIT: "some other conditions" has been put in the range of summation
>   in r.h.s. Now I have some other questions:

I can understand having more questions. Should we ask them in comment line, or make an edit in the question or ask a new question?

What is the policy of the site on this? Is it okay to constantly add more questions in your post?

Comment: You can find here on meta some related discussions. For example [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/question-edited-to-change-meaning) and other posts [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2304).

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak

Comment: This has been asked before and the answer is "no that behavior is not okay".